# QGIS vector line layer doesn't accept Cyrillic letters

Tags: qgis, vector, internationalization

In QGIS 2.6 vector line layer doesn't accept Cyrillic letters, how can I fix this?

For polygon it it works fine but for line and point it only gives me set of question marks - ?????

It's .shp, I don't know about encoding

Answer (score 3):

Create a new line layer with an encoding which is suitable for Cyrillic letters and try again. If it works, copy the features from your old layer into the new one and continue from there.